# Select the union of two layers in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, selections

I'm currently using Photoshop 21.x and I'm not very good in general with it. Could someone please help me with how to make a selection that comprises the union of two layers? And when I say union here, I mean the pixels that both layers have filled in, think of a venn diagram, I would like to make a selection that contains only the overlapping areas of two or more layers.

Thank you!
Kyle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Hold <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd> and left click one of the layers.
- Right click the other layer and choose *Intersect Transparency Mask*.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

These keyboards shortcut should help you :

Ctrl/Cmd + Clic on a layer thumbnail => You have the selection of it

When you already have a selection :

Ctrl/Cmd + Shift + Clic on a Layer thumbnail => You ad the selection of the layer to the one you already have

Ctrl/Cmd + Alt + Clic on a Layer thumbnail => You delete the selection of the layer to the one you already have

Ctrl/Cmd + Alt + Shift + Clic on a Layer thumbnail => You interesect the selection you have and the selection of the layer

By the way, using alt and shift when you create new selections are always helpfull to ad, delete or intersect.

Comment: I marked the other as the answer since it was first but I'm glad to know the shortcut as well